# Save contents of NSTextView as a plaintext file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I'm sure this has been asked and answered before, but I'm struggling to find something that does what I need.  I'm also new to Cocoa development.

Essentially I need to take the contents of an NSTextView and save it as a plaintext (.txt) file.  I'm assuming some sort of formatting has to to occur before writing to file, etc...

Comment: Is your application a document-based one?

Comment: No, the NSTextView gets filled with an output spew from stdout.  I want to be able to then save that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the data from the `NSTextView` by using the `string` method; you can then take that string and write it directly to a file with the `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`
 method of `NSString`.  A quick example for `stdout`-kind of data:

```
[[myTextView string] writeToFile:@"~/example.txt" 
                      atomically:YES 
                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                           error:nil];
```

But you probably should handle errors if you're going to use this code in a more complicated situation.